# Integrate returning 0 for a curve in R

Tags: r, function, integrate

I was wondering why `integrate` in my below code for the curve I'm showing below is returning `0`?

I'm guessing it has something to do with `Vectorize`, but is there a fix?

```
L = Vectorize(function(x) prod(dnorm(c(250, 265, 259), mean = x, sd = 2)))

curve(L, 252, 263)

integrate(L, -Inf, Inf)[[1]] ## why gives '0' ## is it due to `Vectorize`?
```

[image]

Comment: @Dave2e, dave than how can I get the most exact yet possible value?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is *not* that the values of your `L` function are too small. You integrate over a huge range from `-Inf` to `Inf` which makes it difficult for a numerical integration routine to actually 'see' this peak in the integration domain.

The peak will be recognized by `integrate` if you move it to `0` as the procedure will look there with certainty.

```
L = Vectorize(function(x) prod(dnorm(c(250, 265, 259),
              mean = x + 258, sd = 2)))
# curve(L, -10, 10)

integrate(L, -Inf, Inf)
## 1.487655e-08 with absolute error < 1.1e-10
```

This has nothing to do with `Vectorize`. And `integrate` requires its integrand to be vectorized. (I am a bit doubtful about the absolute error.)

You can also try `quadinf` in the *pracma* package that handles infinite integration domains and does not require the function to be vectorized.

```
f = function(x)
        prod(dnorm(c(250, 265, 259), mean = x + 258, sd = 2))
pracma::quadinf(f, -Inf, Inf)$Q
## [1] 1.487658e-08
```

Still, it needs to be able to 'see' the peak.

Comment: Thanks, but why exactly you're adding `258` to the `x` in: `mean = x + 258`?

Comment: Look at your curve and at the result of `curve(L, -10, 10)` for the redefined `L` function.